# Cursor index error while retrieving column data in variable

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I am trying to retrieve `username` from database table when i successfully login my application and show that on my home activity. I am trying to do this through cursor but i am not retrieving the column data. Any suggestions or help please.

**Login function**

```
public String loginUsers(String email,String pwd)
{
Cursor mCursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseWrapper.FUNTUBE + " WHERE _email=? AND _password=?", new String[]{email,pwd});
 if (mCursor != null) {
 if(mCursor.getCount() > 0)
 {
 String name= mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("_username"));
 mCursor.close();
 return name;
 }
 }
 return null;
 }
```

**Login.java**

```
 String user=  FunTubeDBOperations.loginUsers(em, pwd);
 if(true){
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login successfully!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 Intent intent = new Intent(login.this, home.class);
 intent.putExtra("name", user);
 startActivity(intent);
 finish();
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
String user=  FunTubeDBOperations.loginUsers(em, pwd);
 if(true){
    //....    
  }
```

Because `loginUsers` method return `String` if user found in db otherwise `null` value instead of `boolean`. so to check login is valid or not check `user` value for `null` :

```
String user=  FunTubeDBOperations.loginUsers(em, pwd);
     if(user!=null){
        // valid login details
      }else{
        // invalid login details
      }
```

Comment: It isn't showing any data while debugging app. Is my `loginUsers()` function correct

Comment: @tabia: probably `mCursor ` count is 0. check it

Comment: no it is not 0. It crashes the app after this line `String name= mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("_username"));`

Comment: now it works!! i just changed `if(mCursor.getCount() > 0)` to `if(mCursor.moveToFirst())`  :)

Comment: @tabia: Great if working :) this answer help you or not in fixing issue.Thanks